# Javascript not working written inside woocommerce woocommerce_new_order hook inside function.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to call this hook to trigger just before reviewing the order in checkout. But the ajax response show me the same script code as below and nothing in console box, or any javascript function call  made from that hook function not working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'wc_send_order_to_mypage' ,10 , 1 );
function wc_send_order_to_mypage($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $orderId =  $order->get_id();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('<?php echo $orderId; ?>');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: You need after successful checkout or before that?

Comment: Inside checkout page, before order review. I am integrating custom payment method and it need to check payment method on place order button click.

Comment: You are creating custom payment method than you have to look into this https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-woocommerce-payment-gateway/

Answer (score -1):

With that hook you can't write on the page.
If you want to write on the page you have to use a filter.
If you want to write on the page you have to use something else:
[woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text)
[woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review)
Or check the list of hooks or filters
[hook-docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)